# Override case sensitive regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, case-sensitive

Is it possible to override the case sensitivity of a previously defined regex in Perl? For instance, if I were to have the following:

```
my $upper = qr/BLAH/x;
my $lower = qr/$upper/xi;
warn "blah" =~ $lower
```

I'd like the third line to print a positive match.

Comment: On the other hand, you can make "blah" upper case.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over what I'll be searching over. This is more of a code reuse question, so I don't have to make two very similar regex that test either uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the `/i` to the regexp as follows:

```
use re qw( is_regexp regexp_pattern );

sub make_re_case_insensitive {
   my ($re) = @_;

   return "(?i:$re)" if !is_regexp($re);

   my ($pat, $mods) = regexp_pattern($re);
   if ($mods !~ /i/) {
      $re = eval('qr/$pat/'.$mods.'i')
         or die($@);
   }

   return $re;
}
```

But that won't affect `qr/(?-i:BLAH)/`.

---

> *This is more of a code reuse question, so I don't have to make two very similar regex that test either uppercase or lowercase.*

```
my $pat = 'BLAH';
my $re1 = qr/$pat/x;
my $re2 = qr/$pat/xi;
```

Comment: Good answer, and thanks for including the second comment. It doesn't work if something in the string is regex specific though, like a \h character. So my $pat = 'ABC\hXYZ' won't match 'abc xyz'. I'll mark this as the accepted answer if nothing else prevails.

Comment: @DannySullivan: Yes, it does. `my $pat = 'ABC\hXYZ'` and `say 'ok' if 'abc xyz' =~ $re2` prints `ok`

Comment: Excellent call, sorry I missed that. This is exactly what I was looking for.